# VPN and DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, vpn

I am not an expert in this type of solution

We are setting up a solution where we want a client that connects to a VPN to give the DNS addresses (PowerDNS) controlled by us, we would like to be able to determine which specific client is querying our DNS server through the IP address of its computer, however we have assembled a first solution using AWS Client VPN, but the result has not been what was expected, since we see that all the queries to our DNS regardless of the client who makes it, arrive with the same IP address, the VPN Server is doing NAT and therefore it is its IP address that reaches the DNS.

Can any of you provide us with ideas of how we could solve this? if they are ideas oriented with what we have already assembled AWS Client VPN and PowerDNS much better.

Greetings

Comment: Place your DNS server in a subnet accessible without NAT?

Comment: Really difficult to understand what you're asking. Suggest you edit your question to a) Say what you're trying to achieve _clearly_ maybe with a bullet point list b) Seperately, what you've tried and what happened c) Use sentences rather than one huge paragraph as it's really difficult understand as it is. I've done some work in this area and can probably help if you can make it easier for me to understand.